# How can I typeset an extra-long \textbar?

Tags: symbols

This is what I get with `\textbar`:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Usually this is written with a slash: "Wintersemester 2011/2012" or shorter "Wintersemester 2011/12". `\slash` instead of `/` adds a breakpoint after the slash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `\rule`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lpipe}{\rule[-0.4ex]{0.41pt}{2.3ex}}

\begin{document}
Wintersemester 2011 \lpipe\ 2012
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

The optional argument takes a vertical lift, the first mandatory argument takes the line width and the second the height. You may adjust the values to fit your needs (and font settings)

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lpipe}{\smash{\rule[-0.4ex]{0.41pt}{42ex}}}

\begin{document}
Some text to fill the lines and see the \verb+\baselineskip+ increasing.
Now let's type the \lpipe\ pipe. And some more filler text. And some more
filler text. And some more filler text. And some more filler text. More
filler text. And some more filler text. And some more filler text. More
filler text. And some more filler text. And some more filler text.

\bigskip
H\lpipe H\\
H \lpipe\ H
\end{document}
```

### Update 2

I added `\smash` to the definition of `\lpipe` to make it not affect the line height. But I think that the line should be only as heigh as possible without increasing the line (even without `\smash`). Otherwise it will hardly fit to the used font.

To illustrate this I took this picture

[image: bad pipe vs. good pipe]

which is the result of this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lpipe}{\rule[-0.4ex]{0.41pt}{2.3ex}}

\newcommand{\badlpipe}{\smash{\rule[-0.4ex]{0.41pt}{3.2ex}}}

\begin{document}
Some text to fill the lines and see the \verb+\baselineskip+ increasing.
Now let's type the \lpipe\ pipe. And some more filler text. And some more
filler text. And some more filler text. And some more filler text. More
filler text. And some more filler text. And some more filler text. More
filler text. And \badlpipe\ some more filler text. And some more filler text.
\end{document}
```

The `\badlpipe` is a litte to long to not affect the line height, so I used `\smash`. But one can easily see that this is very bad style and looks not good …

Comment: Thanks! How can I prevent these two things: (1) The gap to the right is a bit smaller than to the left. (2) The pipe causes the line height to increase.

Comment: @mcb: I can’t see both problems in my update. Thats the reason why an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is _always_ useful ;-) please create one that shows your document class and font settings. Furthermore I guess the rule won’t increase the line height if it’s adjusted to the font settings …

Comment: You can put the rule inside a `\smash` to remove any possible line height disruptions.

Comment: Set the height to `42ex`, then you'll see what I mean. And concerning (2), I think it’s the font (Platino). I inserted a `\hspace{0.8mm}` to fix it.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. I know that there was a macro for this but forgot it’s name …

Comment: @mcb: (1) Certanly a 24 ex height object will increase the line height but I can’t see any sense in a such and object in the middle of a paragraph. If it increases the line height it’s not well adjusted to the font, I think. But Werner’s suggest would help to do even this. (2) I think that palatino should have no spacing problems with `\lpipe` … how do you load it [MWE … ;-)]?

Comment: The problem is that I have two boxes which are aligned in coloumns next to each other. So one can see that the lines are not aligned after the `\lpipe`. It works with the `\smash`! Thanks. :)

Comment: @mcb: Ahh OK ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

Wintersemester 2012 $\mid$ 2013

\end{document}
```

[image]