# Vertical bar in text mode

Tags: boxes, text-mode

How do I create a vertical bar in text mode, which is a bit thicker and taller than the `|` character?

I used to know how to do this with boxes, but googling no longer turns up any useful resources.

I'm specifically using xelatex.

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46519/how-can-i-typeset-an-extra-long-textbar) what you're looking for?

Comment: You might want to check the topic [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm looking for the `\rule` builtin command:

```
\rule[-0.4ex]{0.2ex}{1.2em}
```

From lshort, the parameters are:

```
\rule[lift]{width}{height}
```

Comment: Great alternative choice.

Comment: But this makes your topic a duplicate of [the one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46519/how-can-i-typeset-an-extra-long-textbar) mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Which one is your “heartbeat girl"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ tipa }
\begin{document}
\textbar

\textpipe\textvertline\texttoneletterstem% need package tipa
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe there is a simpler solution using the builtin `\rule`. I'll post in a second.