# How can I get a slimmer \textbar?

Tags: symbols, width

I use `\textbar` in my headers in order to separate the page number from the section.

```
\thepage\hspace{0.5ex}\textbar\hspace{1ex}\thesection\sectiontitle
```

But I want to slim the thickness of the `\textbar` and to set it to 0.15ex (to match the width of the head rule). The `\textbar` must be a bit higher than the page number and the title of the section (`\textbar` is like this already).

Comment: You can use a `\rule` instead. See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46520/18228

Comment: He says that his definition is ugly; is it the one with smash or the other /

Answer (score 5):

I would scale `\textbar` using `\scalebox{<factor>}[1]` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum,graphicx}
\newcommand{\newtextbar}[1][.7]{\scalebox{#1}[1]{\textbar}}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \setheadrule{0.15ex}
  \sethead{}{\thepage\hspace{0.5ex}\textbar{} \newtextbar\hspace{1ex}\thesection{} \sectiontitle}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

`\newtextbar` has 70% of the width of `\textbar` (as default), although you can adjust the default and the actual using `\newtextbar[<factor>]`. A factor > 1 will make it thicker, while a factor < 1 will make it thinner.