# Vertical bars in chemical equation

Tags: mhchem

I'm trying to write chemical equations with `mhchem`, but I can't compile the code when I insert vertical bars (||) in the formula.

```
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
.
.
\begin{center}
\ce{|M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}|[Al_{x}Si_{t-x}O_{2t}]-IZA}
\end{center}
```

When I write ||, the code don't compile, but if I replace it by [] it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I would like write something like this:

\begin{center}
\ce{|M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}|[Al_{x}Si_{t-x}O_{2t}]-IZA}
\end{center}

I need write || in the formula. I wouldn't like replace it by [ ] because IUPAC rules don't allow.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could split up the `\ce` like so: `|\ce{M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}}| \ce{[Al_{x}Si_{t-x}O_{2t}]-IZA}`

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46519/how-can-i-typeset-an-extra-long-textbar.

Comment: The same question has been posted on `c.t.t.`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rico. I'm going to split up my formula, like you said. And thanks samcarter for your suggestions

Comment: For what it's worth: there's no problem using `|` with `chemformula`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if the bars in my example are in proper places, but the idea is simple: putting them in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\ce{$|$M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}$|$ $|$Al_{x}Si_{t-x}O_{2t}$|$-IZA}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could simply split up you formula.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
|\ce{M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}}| \ce{[Al_{x}Si_{t-x}O_{2t}]-IZA}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other answers offered workarounds. As for the question, why this is not supported by the `\ce` macro, well, the author never considered this particular notation. If you can provide an argument that this is a standard chemical notation (preferably by a IUPAC colored book), he will be happy to include this into one of the next mhchem releases.

Comment: It seems that here is bug. For example `\ce{M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}|}` works, but `\ce{|M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}}` not and `\ce{$|$M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}|}` works again. Also works `\ce{O2|M_{x}(H2O)_{\gamma}|}`. Error is only if vertical bar is in beginning of chem formula.